# Class constructor Redistore cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

i get that error in my console even though i have 'new' in my code

```
 const RedisStore=connectRedis(session)
    const client=redis.createClient()
    
     app.use(
        session(
            {
                name:"kid",
                store :new RedisStore(
                    {
                    disableTouch:true,
                    client:client,
                    })
                ,
```

idk what to try i cant find a sollution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are good you're running v7+ of connect-redis. Whereas in the past you had to initialize express-session separately and pass it in:

```
const RedisStore=connectRedis(session)
```

you only need this instead:

```
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default;
```

and can remove express-session from the declaration, although you'll still need to define your session for express itself. See the end of [this link](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/releases/tag/v7.0.0) in Github issues for further details on the new RedisStore call, and the code section of its Github in general for new boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on Daniel`s answer.
For people using Typescript remember to remove `@types/connect-redis`.

> If you were using @types/connect-redis, remove that package as types are now included in this package.

```
npm remove @types/connect-redis
```

Keeping @types/connect-redis will have you keep the old type specifications giving you a typescript error.
Also change the code like so

```
// until v6
import connectRedis from "connect-redis"
import session from "express-session"
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session)

// after v7
import RedisStore from "connect-redis"
```

You no longer need to pass the session to redis `connectRedis(session)`.
Logs: https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/releases/tag/v7.0.0